# JPA Criteria api with oracle12c JSON_VALUE function

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to crete Criteria API query with JSON_VALUE function() is Oracle12c:

```
select * from orderswhere (JSON_VALUE(duty, '$.department') in ( ? , ? , ? ,? , ? , ? , ?));
```

MODEL:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Trade implements Serializable {
     @Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
     private Map<String, Object> duty;
     .....
}

private Specification<InvoicePurchase> reportFormToSpec(Map<String, Object> 
    params) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
             List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
       if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(params.get("department"))) {
            Predicate predicate = cb.like(cb.function("json_value", String.class,
                    root.get("duty"),
                    cb.literal("$.department"))
                    , params.get("department"));
            predicates.add(predicate);
        }
            return query.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])).getRestriction();
        };

    }
```

But getting exception: o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:  ORA-40454:path expression not a literal

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

ERROC CODE:

```
   2017-11-23 12:26:55.271  WARN 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 40454, SQLState: 99999
   2017-11-23 12:26:55.271 ERROR 11972 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-40454: path expression not a literal
```

Comment: error message:2017-02-15 14:22:13.210  WARN 23176 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 40454, SQLState: 99999
2017-02-15 14:22:13.210 ERROR 23176 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-40454: path expression not a literal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is not working, is that in the background, Hibernate will generate such an SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE JSON_VALUE(?, ?)=?
```

.. and this does not work with Oracle.

The solution is, to inline these values. First a small helper class:

```
public class HibernateInlineExpression extends LiteralExpression<String> {

  public HibernateInlineExpression(CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, String literal) {
      super((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, literal);
  }

  @Override
  public String render(RenderingContext renderingContext) {
      return getLiteral();
  }
}
```

Using the above, you can now do JSON expressions in predicates:

```
cb.equal(cb.function("JSON_VALUE", String.class,
                new HibernateInlineExpression(cb, "JSON_COLUMN"),
                new HibernateInlineExpression(cb, "'$.my.json.property'")),
  new LiteralExpression<>((CriteriaBuilderImpl) cb, String.class, "somevalue"));
```

Of course the above is a Hibernate-specific implementation, users of EclipseLink, etc. have to come up with something similar. See my [blog post about using JSON functions of Oracle from JPA/Hibernate](http://www.istvandevai.com/2018/02/using-oracle-json-functions-via-jpa-and.html) for some other tricks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helps. I have used this solution for function "JSON_EXISTS", but this time I have no luck...can you pls take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75681678/jpa-predicate-calling-oracle-json-function-caused-sql-error